# Which is the best LN software?

Tags: lightning-network

I know that software for the Lightning Network can only be used with testnet and not with real Bitcoin yet.

I'm trying to choose one LN software among C-Lightning, ACINQ, AmikoPay, Thunder, Lit and Lnd in order to study and test it. What are the main differences between them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Obivously, the question and this answer are subjective based on personal experiences. I've only used LND and C-Lightning, which are arguably the most popular. The following is a summary of my experiences:

[LND](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd)

LND is built in GO and requires a special version of Bitcoin built in GO as well. The install process is well documented and pretty straightforward. However, I had issues with configuring Glide, which is required to install the dependencies. Additionally, I was hesitant to rely on the GO version of Bitcoin to stay supported. Supposedly, there's a pull request to make the changes needed in the Core version, but still... I considered it a risk. Once past the dependency issues, LND worked great. I would have continued using it, but I wanted to try other implementations.

[C-Lightning](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning)

Since I run Core's version of Bitcoin and prefer my daemons to be in C (again, an objective position based on personal experiences), I tried C-Lightning next. There weren't any issues with installation on Ubuntu and it's been purring along since. The only problems I've had are around documentation, which I'd say LND has done a slightly better job with so far.

---

In summary, the above Lightning implementations are great and I would recommend either. Both have fantastic teams behind them and are consistently committing updates.

I ended up sticking with C-Lightning because it had the architecture and dependencies I'm most comfortable with and have the most experience with (Bitcoin Core and C). Since both implementations are still a work in progress and documentation is ongoing, I find myself continuously in the code figuring out errors and options. If I was more of a GO developer, I'd probably choose LND.